# making slave server as master for another server

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, master-slave

I have three servers, Server X, Y, and Z.
I have the main mysql DB on X (innodb DB).
now I have created Master-Slave from X to Y. everything is working fine here.
and now i set Y as a master for Z.
when i do show slave status on Z (the third server)

```
show slave status\G
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
...
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
...
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
```

but the data is not synchronized and nothing has been moved from Y to Z.
any idea about what might cause this??
**EDIT**
in my.cnf on server Y, i have the following conf:

```
log-slave-updates=ON
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

but in show variables like '%slave%' i have

```
show variables like '%slave%';
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| init_slave                |        |
| log_slave_updates         | OFF    |
| slave_compressed_protocol | OFF    |
| slave_exec_mode           | STRICT |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp   |
| slave_net_timeout         | 3600   |
| slave_skip_errors         | OFF    |
| slave_transaction_retries | 10     |
| sql_slave_skip_counter    |        |
+---------------------------+--------+
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have started Y with [--log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) option so that update received from X are logged by Y to its binary log.

---

> in my.cnf on server Y, i have the following conf:
>
> ```
> log-slave-updates=ON
> ```

Use the boolean value instead of switch value:

```
log-slave-updates=true
```

The results:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%slave%';
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| init_slave                |        |
| log_slave_updates         | ON     |
| slave_compressed_protocol | OFF    |
| slave_exec_mode           | STRICT |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp   |
| slave_net_timeout         | 3600   |
| slave_skip_errors         | OFF    |
| slave_transaction_retries | 10     |
| sql_slave_skip_counter    |        |
+---------------------------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i have edited my question... please advise

Comment: It means that you **haven't** restarted MySQL after changing `my.cnf` file.

Comment: sure i did many times... it is old configuration... however i just did it again and have the samething!! :(

Comment: updated my answer.